# Android Studio can't stop process ExampleUnitTest

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am new to Android testing. I wanted to try run ExampleUnitTest which created as default by Android Studio and see what happens. It runned perfectly, but process didn't stop after running end. Whenever I click on "Stop" button from Android Studio nothing happens. How can I force it stop?

[There is a ss taken from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOSg9.png)
[image]

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem, currently have 4 processes running at the same time that I am unable to stop. Did you solve it?